# Recuperar um arquivo no GIT

Tags: git

Eu tenho duas pastas (teste-git1 e teste-git2), em ambas dei um clone do repositório do servidor.

Se eu excluir um arquivo sem querer dentro da pasta do teste-git1, como eu faço pra recuperá-lo? eu tentei dar `git pull origin master`, mas aparece essa mensagem:

```
$ git pull origin master
From github.com:asdasdadasasd/teste-git
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Na minha pasta teste-git1, eu exclui o arquivo `joao.txt`, depois fiz um

```
git status
`deleted:    joao.txt`
```

Até aí ok, mas como eu faço pra recuperar esse dado de novo? Eu tenho que dar um clone de novo? Tem um jeito de recuperar de novo pelo pull?

Comment: testa `$ git reset --hard origin/master`, e repara que isso vai apagar alterações locais que tenhas feito.

Comment: Você não tentou dar um *merge*? Quando você dá um `pull` você está apenas trazendo conteúdo de um repositório para outro mas não está colocando na sua pasta de trabalho. Mas tem  outras formas de fazer o que você quer.

Comment: agora está esquisito, eu exclui a pasta teste-git1 e clonei os arquivos do servidor de novo pra uma nova pasta com o mesmo nome (teste-git1), agora fui tentar adicionar novos arquivos nesta pasta recém clonada e fui verificar no git status, não apareceu nenhuma alteração/modificação, etc.

Comment: muito cuidado com o "reset --hard" o git irá remover todas as alterações até o que estiver no origin/master. Sempre que utilizar este comando tenha certeza do quê esta fazendo. Aliás muita certeza!

Comment: @FlávioGranato o _reset_ só força a pasta local a ter o mesmo que a pasta remota. Concordo que deve ser usada com precaução mas não muda nada do `origin/master`

Comment: "reset --hard" remove todo e qualquer arquivo e alteração que o git conheça e sem possibilidade de recuperação, não é só força a pasta local a ter o mesmo da pasta remota... não sei o nível de conhecimento do @João mas é sempre avisar né... :-)

Comment: meu nível de conhecimento é: aprendendo git desde ontem. que comandos essenciais um grupo de desenvolvedores de uma empresa usa? git status, git pull, git checkout, git push, git add, git commit e git log? tem mais dicas?

Comment: @João, mesmo com sua descrição, é mais fácil se você nos der a sequência de comandos em cada repositório clonado, acompanhado da saída no `git status`. Assim fica mais simples explicar e ajuda :).

Answer (score 3):

Dado que vc clonou o repositório e logo após isso deletou o arquivo (o status `deleted` que vc disse), pra recuperá-lo basta rodar:

```
git checkout <nome do arquivo excluído>
```

Este comando descarta todas as modificações realizadas no arquivo passado como parâmetro desde o último commit (registro de versão). Mas o comando `checkout` é mais poderoso do que isso, é aceita várias outras opções: [git-checkout docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: Está funcionalidade tambem serve para quando eu ainda nao fiz o push do repo local?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar estes comandos:

```
git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- <file_path>
```

Onde -n X é a quantidade de commits anteriores que o arquivo exista.

```
git checkout <deleting_commit>^ -- <file_path>
```

este comando é para fazer puxar o arquivo novamente.

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repo) tem o post com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Respondi isso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39296006/5869837): Minha resposta vale que casos onde você apenas usou :

```
git checkout -- .
```

antes de commitar algo.

Answer (score 0):

Para restaurar o arquivo basta rodar o seguinte comando:

```
git restore joao.txt
```

Comment: Edite a resposta e coloque a sintaxe do comando, uma descrição do que faz e o link para documentação pois estão sinalizando para remover a sua resposta.